# Hiding console output produced by os.system

Tags: python, shell

I am calling this piece of code, but it produces some output in the console where I ran the python script (due to tee command):

```
os.system("echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches")
```

This version does not produce console output but is there another way?

```
os.system('sudo bash -c "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"')
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To answer the question based on its title in the most *generic* form:

To **suppress *all* output from `os.system()`**, **append `>/dev/null 2>&1` to the shell command, which silences both stdout and stderr**; e.g.:

```
import os
os.system('echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches >/dev/null 2>&1')
```

Note that `os.system()` by design passes output from the calling process' stdout and stderr streams *through* to the console (terminal) - your Python code never sees them.

Also, `os.system()` does *not* raise an exception if the shell command fails and instead returns an exit code; note that it takes additional work to extract the shell command's true exit code: you need to extract the high byte from the 16-bit value returned, by applying `>> 8` (although you can rely on a return value other than `0` implying an error condition).

---

Given the above limitations of `os.system()`, **it is generally worthwhile to use the functions in the `subprocess` module** instead:

For instance, `subprocess.check_output()` could be used as follows:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output('echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches', shell=True)
```

The above will:

- capture *stdout* output and return it (with the return value being ignored in the example above)
- pass *stderr* output through; passing `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` as an additional argument would also capture stderr.
- raise an error, if the shell command fails.

Note: **Python 3.5** introduced `subprocess.run()`, a more flexible successor to both `os.system()` and `subprocess.check_output()` - see https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module

---

Note:

- The reason that the OP is employing `tee` in the first place - despite not being interested in stdout output - is that a naïve attempt to use `> ...` instead would be interpreted *before* `sudo` is invoked, and thus fail, because the required privileges to write to `/proc/sys/...` haven't been granted yet.
- Whether you're using `os.system()` or a `subprocess` function, *stdin* is not affected by default, so if you're invoking your script from a terminal, you'll get an interactive password prompt when the `sudo` command is encountered (unless the credentials have been cached).

Answer (score 5):

Write directly to the proc pseudo file instead via Python i/o lib.

This will require your script to run as root (via `sudo`), which means you should limit its scope to being an admin only tool. This also allows the script to run on boxes where `sudo` requires a password.

Example:

```
with open("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches", "w") as drop_caches:
    drop_caches.write("3")
```

Comment: I would not consider running the entire script as root as a solution.

Comment: @Petesh, if a script requires root privileges to run then the user must understand the risks. On a system, where `sudo` requires a password, the OP's original script would fail. Requiring a user to `sudo` my code, would make the risks and intention very obvious.

Comment: Petesh, the script we talk about already requires sudo to call the command. Your point has no relevance here.

Comment: `open("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches", "w").write("3")` also acceptable

Answer (score 4):

```
subprocess.check_call(command,stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

you forgot to add stderr.

Comment: worked like magic. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You also can use this simple method of subprocess module.

```
command = 'echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
subprocess.check_call(shlex.split(command),stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

All outputs will be passed to DEVNULL. Any issues with the command will be reported by an exception. No issues means no output.