# Command prompt all in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-prompt

I'm basically trying to make command prompt run in python it should be simple enough I have this code here

```
import os
fileplace = 'C/:'
a = input(fileplace)
b = os.system('cmd /c '+a)
if b == 1:
    print('error with command')
else:
    print('ran '+a)
```

and I would like to know how I could print the output and maybe hide the command prompt when I run a command

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os


cmd = input('C/:')
stream = os.popen(f'cmd /c {cmd}')
output = stream.read()

if output == '':
    print(f'Error with {cmd}')
else:
    print(f'ran {cmd}')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code. First, the default error for a success `os.system` is 0. The error code can very depending on what happens, so identifying it with `b == 1` will not suffice. For example if you used an incorrect command (i.e., command not found), it will give you 32512 on Unix.

So here's my suggested revision to the code with some comments to changes:

```
import os
fileplace = 'C:\'.  # Note that I changed this for correct path (in case you use it)
a = input(fileplace)  # I get that you're trying to get a path but you're not passing the full path
b = os.system('cmd /c '+a)  #Not sure what /c is intended for here
if b == 0: # This will pass on successful execution
    print('ran '+a)
else:  # This will not pass 
    print('error with cmd')
```

As far as hiding the message, you can pass it to `dev/null`. However, since you're on Windows I'm not entirely sure how that will work as the solution I found was for Linux/UNIX system. This might give you some context for avoiding the message on screen, but won't answer the second question: [Hiding console output produced by os.system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985863/hiding-console-output-produced-by-os-system)

Comment: I think the equivalent in Windows is ```nul```