# Executing CMD in Python with os

Tags: python

My code:

```
import os

os.system("pip install colorama")
```

This starts to print the actual command and such, is there a way to execute this without anything being printed. Or even like for example a variable with the response and I can handle it from there? I don't want a massive text, just a simple one saying it was installed etc.

Comment: Do these help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006238/how-do-i-hide-the-console-when-i-use-os-system-or-subprocess-call, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985863/hiding-console-output-produced-by-os-system and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931392/python-hide-console-window

Comment: You can use `subprocess.Popen()` to run the command like this:

    `import subprocess
    subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/k", "pip install colorama"])`

This might also help:

    `subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/k", "pip install colorama"], shell=True)`

Answer (score 2):

You could probably redirect the output into `/dev/null`, so you could do something like the following:

```py
import os

os.system(“pip install colorama > /dev/null 2>&1“)
```

Note that this would also redirect the errors (because of the `2>&1`). If you want to keep errors, you should remove that.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably use echo Off as the first command, then run colorama, then use echo to say whatever final message you want, like this:

```
import os
os.system("@echo off")
os.system("pip install colorama")
os.system("echo on")
os.system("echo Colorama installed.")
```